# Drag file from desktop to IE and upload

Tags: internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

For a project I'm working on I would like the user to be able to drag a file from the desktop or windows explorer and drop it on a web page in IE and have it uploaded to the web server. I've read that its possible with ActiveX but have not found anything about it.

Anyone know how to do this and where I can get what I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Browser Plus](http://browserplus.yahoo.com/) from Yahoo.

Cross browser support, but needs an install.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for drag-n-drop to work the user will have to install a plugin. That's how it's done in services like [Projectplace](http://www.projectplace.com) at least.

Comment: Right, but he already mentioned that he's willing to use an ActiveX component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work cross-browser, you should consider a Java applet.

Otherwise, I believe you are right that a custom ActiveX component should solve it :)